# C# Web API using Dapper to insert data using a stored procedure - unable to get inserted record Id

Tags: c#, dapper

I'm new to Dapper - please help me. How can I get the inserted record value after a successful insert?

Stored procedure:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE Sp_InsertTestData
    @Name varchar(50),
    @gender int,
    @refres int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Test_Master (Name, Gender) 
    VALUES (@Name, @gender);

    SELECT @refres = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    SELECT @refres as M_SID
END
```

When I execute this stored procedure in SQL like this:

```sql
DECLARE @refres INT
EXEC Sp_InsertTestData 'test12',1,@refres
```

I'm getting an output showing the last inserted row's value.

But when this stored procedure is executed from C# code, every time I'm getting a value of 1:

```cs
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnection")))
{
    con.Open();

    SqlTransaction sqltrans = con.BeginTransaction();

    var param = new DynamicParameters();
    param.Add("@Name", Bindtestmaster.Name);
    param.Add("@gender", Bindtestmaster.Gender);
    param.Add("@refres");

    res = con.Execute("Sp_InsertTestData", param, sqltrans, 0, CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this but perhaps `res` is a count of the number of records updated which will be one. What does the database hold after insert

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are getting the result of the stored procedure call, which tells you the number of rows inserted (which is 1).

You want to read the output parameter `@refres` (and add it to your `DynamicParameters` as an output parameter)

```cs
/* ... */
param.Add("@refres", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
con.Execute("Sp_InsertTestData", param, sqltrans,0,CommandType.StoredProcedure);
var yourId = param.Get<int>("@refres");
```

Btw, on your stored procedure instead of:

```sql
select @refres=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

You might want to prefer this:

```sql
SET @refres = SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT
```

And I'm not sure what that last `SELECT` is there for

Or directly output the inserted ID (using the `OUTPUT` SQL clause on the `INSERT`) and then you could read the result, and not have an output parameter at all.

Answer (score 1):

Since your stored procedure also *selects* the output:

```sql
select @refres as M_SID
```

An easier way of doing this might be:

```cs
var id = con.ExecuteScalar<int>("Sp_InsertTestData", new {
    Name = Bindtestmaster.Name,
    gender = Bindtestmaster.Gender
}, sqltrans, 0, CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

and forget `DynamicParameters` etc. You could *also* consider using the `OUTPUT` clause in the SQL, to simplify it:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE Sp_InsertTestData
    @Name varchar(50), @gender int
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Test_Master(Name, Gender)
    OUTPUT INSERTED.Id -- whatever the column is here
    VALUES (@Name, @gender);
END
```